# Error when limit the server resources of the user

Tags: mysql

when I try to limit the user's server resources by using the GRANT command I have an error

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'francis'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'frank';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL ON customer.* TO 'francis'@'localhost'
    ->          WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20
    ->             MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10
    ->              MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 5
    ->               MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 2;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20
>               MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 10
>                MAX_CON' at line 2

But whithout GRANT its work :

```
mysql> DROP USER 'francis'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)
mysql> CREATE USER 'francis'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'frank'
    -> WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 20;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)
```

Is there an error in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you try to run code targeting version 5.7 on version 8.0.

The possibility to specify resource options in a `GRANT` is available up to version 5.7 but has been removed in 8.0.

Compare [the documentation of 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) against [the one of 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) regarding this -- note the `resource_option` option token in the 5.7 version of the document is missing in the 8.0 version.

5.7:

> ```
> GRANT
>   ...
>   [WITH {GRANT OPTION | resource_option} ...]
> ```

8.0:

> ```
> GRANT
>   ...
>   [WITH GRANT OPTION]
> ```

For changes to the nonprivilege characteristics of existing accounts, i.e. the resource options, `ALTER USER` has to be used in 8.0 and upwards. Or you can include it in the `CREATE USER` statement for new accounts as you already did.